# GetAsyncKeyState and some problems?

Tags: user32

Why do i get more than 1 (a few hundred) key hit on a single press while using GetAsyncKeyState. It prints a hundred of a same key while i just pressed it once. 
Thanks,

Comment: Are you looping while calling GetAsyncKeyState? Keep in mind that the computer can perfectly well check the key state a few hundred times in what it takes you to release the key.

Comment: whats best i can do here? i mean i tried putting sleep(100) but what if some computers are slower? then there will be dropped characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAsyncKeyState` tells you the **state** of the keyboard, whether a key is down/up, not whether it has been pressed since last call. If you call it in a loop, you will get "key is down" for as long as you keep the key down - and that loop executes a lot faster than you can move your fingers.

If you want keyboard **events** handle `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.

If you want a global hotkey, use `RegisterHotKey`

Comment: hmmm...Got it, do you suggest any solution?

Comment: i'm trying to put a shortcut for my app so that when goes to the tray i can call it back while its not focused.

Comment: and make sure you choose a hotkey that doesn't have a meaning in the program that the focus when the user hits your hot key.